# NGINX $http_user_agent change for specific browser

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Good day everyone, tell me how you can change the $http_user_agent part in a request to my server.
I tried to do so, but something went wrong

tryed:

```
server {


set $ua $http_user_agent;

if ($http_user_agent ~ "^YABrowser/ (.+)$") {

    set $ua "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 $1";

}

proxy_set_header User-Agent $us;


}
```

edit part of this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.5.1.769 (corp) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
```

will become this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

but only for devices with this browser, not for all

Comment: Your question has a typo: `$ua` and `$us`. Your non-functional example is not sufficient to diagnose the issue you are encountering. Please edit your question and add a complete `server` block.